# React-hook-form `register` not registering field with name has a single quote in the middle,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have integrated react-hook-form with my form, where it is not registering field with name has single quote in the middle. Instead it stripes single quote .

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";
//App component
export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
//onSubmit Handler
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
//field name value
const name = "Patient's Name";
//Return 
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register(`register ${name}`)} />
      <select {...register("gender")}>
        <option value="female">female</option>
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
//Renders
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

output : {register Patients Name: undefined, gender: "female"}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to assign the input field name as the value.  You could try using the 'name' as the field name and `${name}` as the input value.

Something like this may work better:

```html
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("name")} />
      <select {...register("gender")}>
        <option value="female">female</option>
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

If you really need a dynamic input field name, you could try:

```js
const name = "Patient\'s Name";

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register({name})} />
      <select {...register("gender")}>
        <option value="female">female</option>
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm on `react-hook-form` v7. Your answer triggers an error "path.split" is not a function